# how to create a button with link in javaScript

Tags: javascript

ı want to create a button with link but it does not work can you help me

thats my code :var btn= document.createElement("button");btn.innerText="yeni tuş";document.body.appendChild(btn);

ı try create div and add href into it but did not work

var dv= document.createElement("div");dv.innerHTML = " <button>new</button> "
dv.style.color = 'red';
dv.setAttribute('href', 'www.google.com'); document.body.appendChild(dv);

Comment: "but did not work" - what does that mean?

Comment: The `href` attribute applies to the `<a>` tag, not `<button>` or any other tag. You can either style an `<a>` tag to look like a button with CSS, or have the `<button>` element use JavaScript and change the `window.location` value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-do-i-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Preferably, style a link (`<a>`) like a button. "Links _take you_ somewhere, buttons _do_ something."

Answer (score 2):

Either create an `a` element and style it to look like a button *or* create a `button` element and make clicking it set `window.location`.

```js
const aElem = document.createElement('a');
aElem.href = 'https://google.com';
aElem.innerHTML = 'link';
aElem.classList.add('btn');
document.body.appendChild(aElem);

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

const btnElem = document.createElement('button');
btnElem.onclick = () => window.location = 'https://google.com';
btnElem.innerHTML = 'button';
document.body.appendChild(btnElem);
```

```css
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 0px 6px 2px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```